# How to restore accidentaly removed file of FreeBSD base system?

Tags: freebsd, restore

I accidentally removed `/etc/rc.d/rtadvd` from my FreeBSD system (8.2-RELEASE)

What is the best way of getting such system file restored?

Comment: What **filesystem** are you using? If it's ZFS, you might be lucky :)

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz No, it's UFS. And I didn't make any changes to that file, so I just have to find the default file somewhere and put it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small further investigation learned that the base versions are stored in the kernel source in `/usr/src/etc`.

So a cp `/usr/src/etc/rc.d/rtadvd /etc/rc.d/rtadvd` solved my problems.

Answer (score 2):

The [CVSWeb](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/etc/rc.d/rtadvd) got it covered, but `ident /etc/rc.d/rtadvd` on *my* 8.2-RELEASE-p3 system yields

```
 $FreeBSD: src/etc/rc.d/rtadvd,v 1.12.2.1.6.1 2010/12/21 17:09:25 kensmith Exp $
```

which I can't find there... rev 1.12 is tagged `RELENG_8`.

Answer (score 1):

This file is in the base system, so grab the base system archive and extract that particular file.

```
cd /tmp
wget -r ftp://ftp.fi.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/i386/8.2-RELEASE/base
cd /
cat /tmp/ftp.fi.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/i386/8.2-RELEASE/base/base.?? |
tar -xzf - etc/rc.d/rtadvd
```

Alternatively, since this file is identical to its source, you can grab `etc/rc.d/rtadvd` from the source tree, either on your system if you've unpacked it (`/usr/src/etc/rc.d/rtadvd`) or on the web. I'd expect the file to be in [`/etc/rc.d` in the CVS source tree view with the `RELENG_8_2_0_RELEASE` tag](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/etc/rc.d/?only_with_tag=RELENG_8_2_0_RELEASE); I don't know why it doesn't appear there. You can get it from the [svn source tree view in the `release/8.2.0` branch](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/8.2.0/etc/rc.d/rtadvd).